# Logging into PostgreSQL on Linux

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have installed Postgre SQL on my local Ubuntu 20.04 as described here:

https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-postgresql-13-on-ubuntu/

In order to log in to Postge SQL I have to switch to user postgres first

```
(base) irbis@irbis-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo su - postgres
[sudo] password for irbis: 
postgres@irbis-System-Product-Name:~$ psql
psql (13.8 (Ubuntu 13.8-1.pgdg20.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Without switching to postgres there is an error:

```
(base) irbis@irbis-System-Product-Name:~$ psql
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "irbis" does not exist
```

So the question is - what I have to do in order to

1. Start Console by default (with user irbis)
2. Type psql (not psql -U or any other)
3. Postgres started

Maybe create role etc. Please provide me with code snippet.
I am a newbie to Postgres and don't want to break anything.

Comment: This sounds like a Unix permissions issue.  Make sure the Postgres executables in the bin folder have the appropriate execute permissions, the data and log folders have write permissions and your user is set up properly.  My guess is you will need to add the group to your user id.

Comment: There are several ways to do it.  You should read the documentation, rather than tutorials of dubious quality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the current authentication method (presumably 'peer', you should create a user and database named "irbis".

Log into postgresql using the currently functional `sudo` method, then

```
create user irbis;
create database irbis owner irbis;
```

If you never want to use the `sudo` method again, then you should create the user 'irbis' as a superuser.  But that will make it more likely that you will accidentally break things in the future.  Your 'daily' user account should probably not be a database superuser.